# How to use conditional operator with string interpolation?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator, c#-6.0

> I am currently using this technique:

```
...
    string s = user.Gender ? "Mr." : "Mrs.";
    string body = $@"Dear {s} {user.First_name}..."
...
```

> I want to do something like:

```
...
    string body = $"Dear {return user.Gender ? "Mr." : "Mrs."} {user.First_name}..."
...
```

Comment: Use parenthesis for the expression: `$"Dear {(user.Gender ? "Mr." : "Mrs.")}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put parenthesis around the expression like so:

```cs
string body = $"Dear {(user.Gender ? "Mr." : "Mrs.")} {user.First_name}...";
```

The reason for that is the colon which signals a format string for something.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do so with a pair of paranteces around your conditional expression, but a better solution would be to make the greeting reusable by defining a property on the class:

```
public class User {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
    public string Title { get => Gender ? "Mr." : "Mrs."; }
    public string Greeting { get => $"{Title} {FirstName} {LastName}"; }
}

void run()
{
    var user = new User { Gender = true, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
    string simpleSolution = $"Dear {(user.Gender ? "Mr." : "Mrs.")} {user.FirstName} {user.LastName}, hello and welcome.";
    string betterSolution = $"Dear {user.Greeting}, hello and welcome.";
}
```